# How to confirm for JavaScript asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, async-await

How should I confirm in any other way that the flexStuff() function call has been done asynchronously?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  flexStuff();
  async function flexStuff() {
    let tr = '{"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX":"ajax",\
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#inherited_properties":"CSS",\
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener":"event listeners"\
}';
    const obj121 = JSON.parse(tr);
    for (let key in obj121) {
      d1 = document.createElement('div');
      d1.setAttribute('id', obj121[key]);
      d1.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj121[key]}</a>`;
      document.querySelector('.my_flexx').appendChild(d1);
    }
    await 2022;
  }

});
```

```css
.my_flexx {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: left;
}

.my_flexx div {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  /*will override the green color*/
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_flexx"></div>
```

Comment: The call is synchronous.

Comment: @jabaa no, there is a `await 2022;` :D

Comment: @YanickRochon Yes, everything after`await 2022;` is evaluated asynchronously :D

Comment: @jabaa right also confusing because refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
it says quote 'an async function without an await expression will run synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.'so how to overcome

Comment: @jabaa the same page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function also has a quote that 'Top-level code, up to and including the first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously' so how to overcome..i am confused

Comment: I don't understand. Your question is how to confirm an asynchronous call? Did you change the question? You should ask a new question. The part of the function before and including `await 2022;` runs synchronously. The part after `await 2022;` runs asynchronously.

Comment: i didnt edit it , edit was done by j08691 ; you can check the edited section

Comment: I mean it seems like you're asking a new question in the comments. The question in the title and body is how to confirm the function is called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an async function without an await expression will run synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.

Yes, everything in the async function will run synchronously until `await` is encountered.

Examples:

```js
async function withoutAwait() {
  console.log('without await')
}

async function withAwait() {
  await 0
  console.log('with await')
}

console.log('start')
withoutAwait()
withAwait()
console.log('end')
```

```js
let a = 0

async function changeA() {
  a = 20
  await 0
  a = 30
}

console.log('start', a)
changeA().then(() => console.log('after change', a))
console.log('end', a)
```

P.S.

JavaScript code runs in one thread. No two lines of code run at the same time.

Asnychrouns code just stops executing when it encounters `await` and goes back to the next fragment when the thread is free.

```js
const results = []

async function f1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    await results.push('f1')
    await 0
  }
}

async function f2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    await results.push('f2')
  }
}

f1()
f2()
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(results)
}, 100)
```

Comment: very useful, your first example is interesting . if you can explain the concept for how did the end appear in the middle.

Comment: When you use `await` the processing of the function stops and go back to the caller. Everything after await will run later when the micro-task queue is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Just use different functions that you can chain. Since your execution is async, then you need to stop thinking synchronously.

```
async function loadStuff() {
   // perform async loading...
}

async function doMoreStuff() {
   // continue with more stuff
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   loadStuff().then(() => doMoreStuff());
});
```

---

#### Edit 1

These two functions are essentially equivalent :

```
async function somethingA() {
  // synchronous code

  return "SomeValue";
}

function somethingB() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    // synchronous code

    resolve("SomeValue");
  });
}
```

The `async`/`await` syntax is just cleaner.

Comment: refer developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/… it says quote 'an async function without an await expression will run synchronously so your code comment    // perform async loading wont work asynchrusly?

Comment: @logogomez see **Edit 1**.

Comment: By the way is the below code valid:async function foo() {
 await(1);
  return Promise.resolve(2009);
}

Comment: @logogomez technically, yes, you can "await" any expression; `await 1` is equivalent to `Promise.resolve(1)`, so the above code would be like `return Promise.resolve(1).then(() => Promise.resolve(2009))`. It will not generate any error, but it won't do anything useful either.