# async await execution in javascript

Tags: async-await

I found some SO questions/answers but I am unable to get the async await javascript concept right..please advise ..my question  is **Should not console.log('end') be executed two times?** .

```js
debugger;

async function withoutAwait() {
  console.log('without await')
} 

async function withAwait() {
  await 0
  console.log('with await')
}

console.log('start')
withoutAwait()
withAwait()
console.log('end')
```

credit to question goes to Konrad Linowski:[async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899801/how-to-confirm-for-javascript-asynchronous-calls))

Comment: @konrad-linkowski as per your answer the point I am stuck is that i am under impression that console.log('end') will execute AGAIN after the function call 'withAwait()' is done...pls help my understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `console.log('end')` will not be executed two times. The Javascript is synchronous. That means that every instructions are executed one after another. With the keyword `async` you indicate that you want to execute once the instruction is finished.

If your function `withAwait` takes 25 seconds, then your `console.log('with Await')` will be fired 25 seconds after. Meanwhile the `console.log('end')` will be fired right after calling your function.

Comment: Can you help me better visualise step by step?

Comment: In Javascript every instructions are executed one after another. It does look if the instruction is finished to go to the next one. Some instructions are longer than others : fetching datas, processing huge amount of datas. By giving the keyword `async`, you put your instruction in a stack that is executed when Javascript decide it has time to execute it. That is why you got your `console.log('end')` before your `console.log('with await')`. Javascript understand that you want this function to be executed when Javascript has time, so it won't block the rest of the program.

Comment: But once the function is done with it's execution it goes back to the instructions left. But since you already had printed `end`, then it can't print it again. @logogomez

Comment: the point I am stuck is that i am under impression that console.log('end') will execute AGAIN after the function call 'withAwait()' is done..

Comment: No, it can't because as I explained before the rest of the code is executed before the execution of the function. An instruction cannot be executed twice if it is called once in a program. If you want to have `end` printed after your function you need to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) to chain your execution

Answer (score 0):

There's only one line of code with `console.log('end')` and it isn't inside a function (let alone a function that gets called multiple times) so no, it shouldn't be called twice.

Comment: i was expecting end to be called again as the 2nd function (withAwait() ) is finished, but  the whole program ends

Comment: can you help me better visualise step by step,thanks